# Why is select query not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to select each PartNum, WarehouseCode, and OnhandQty from the "StkPart" attributes and select the plant from the "Plant" attribute.  There is only one "Plant" in this xml file and the "Plant" would be associated with each row from the "StkPart" attribute.
For Example:

```
   PartNum   WarehouseCode   OnhandQty  Plant
1. 10-12345     Corona         150      MfgSys
2. 10-12351     Cork             1      MfgSys
3. 10-51617a    Here           198      MfgSys
4. 10-97654     There           67      MfgSys
```

This is what I have been trying (The XML code is at the bottom):
This code works and enters the data into my table:

```
USE  Database
GO

CREATE TABLE XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Test\StockStatusReport30597.XML', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML
```

Then I try to select the data, but this is not working:

```
USE Database
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT PartNum
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ReportDataSet/PartNum')
WITH 
(
PartNum [varchar](50) '@PartNum'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

**How do I get the above code to work?**

Here is the XML file to download:
http://wikisend.com/download/101282/StockStatusReport30597.XML

Comment: The xml has unspecified namespaces.

Comment: @Laurence Thanks for responding.  I'm new to XML.  What does the unspecified namespaces have to do with my issue?

Comment: It means anyone trying to use your example will get an error on the insert statement.

Comment: I added the XML file in the link, due to Laurences statement above.  This is the whole file with no deletions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```sql
Declare @xml xml = N'<ReportDataSet 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    ...
    </ReportDataSet>'

Select
    N.value('PartNum[1]', 'varchar(20)') PartNum,
    N.value('WarehouseCode[1]', 'varchar(20)') WarhouseCode,
    N.value('OnhandQty[1]', 'int') OnhandQty,
    @xml.value('(/ReportDataSet/Plant/Plant)[1]', 'varchar(20)') Plant
from
    @xml.nodes('/ReportDataSet/StkPart') as T(n)
```

I've cut some stuff out of the example below to fit into the limitations of SQLFiddle, but it worked with the query from the question with appropriate namespaces added:

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23886)</kbd>**

For your big data example, you'll need to set the default namespace for the query:

```
With xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.epicor.com/Mfg/100')
Select
    N.value('PartNum[1]', 'varchar(20)') PartNum,
    N.value('WarehouseCode[1]', 'varchar(20)') WarhouseCode,
    N.value('OnhandQty[1]', 'decimal(10,2)') OnhandQty,
    @xml.value('(/ReportDataSet/Plant/Plant)[1]', 'varchar(20)') Plant
from 
    @xml.nodes('/ReportDataSet/StkPart') as T(n)
```

Comment: Ok, Awesome, but how do I add the appropriate namespaces to the xml code once it has been brought into the sql table?

Comment: @Kevin I've tried against your big data set and realized you also have a default namespace. This needs to be specified in the query. I've updated the answer.